Countable intersection of nested sets
I consider a sequence of non empty subsets defined on a set $X$ and  decreasing for the inclusions that is $A_{n+1}\subset A_{n}$ for all $n\geq 0$.
I would like to prove that if $\bigcap_{n\geq 0}A_{2n+1}\neq\emptyset$ then $\bigcap_{n\geq 0}A_n\neq\emptyset$.
Attempt :
We notice that
$$
\bigcap_{n\geq 0}A_n=\bigcap_{n\geq 0}(A_{2n}\cap A_{2n+1}) = (\bigcap_{n\geq 0}A_{2n})\cap (\bigcap_{n\geq 0}A_{2n+1})
$$
By hypothesis $(\bigcap_{n\geq 0}A_{2n+1})$ is non empty and
$$
\forall n\geq 0, A_{2n+1}\subset A_{2n}\implies \emptyset\neq\bigcap_{n\geq 0}A_{2n+1}\subset\bigcap_{n\geq 0}A_{2n}
$$
The inverse inclusion is also true so that the intersection over odd or even indices is in fact equal.
Which proves that $\bigcap_{n\geq 0}A_n\neq\emptyset$
I would like to know if such a proof is correct please
Thank you a lot !

As notice in the comments, we can conclude directly from tiding the hypothesis of decreasing sequence
$$
\bigcap_{n\geq 0}A_n=\bigcap_{n\geq 0}(A_{2n}\cap A_{2n+1}) = \bigcap_{n\geq 0}A_{2n+1}\neq\emptyset
$$

(Based on my reading of what you wrote) So far, all that you've shown is that $ \cap A_n$ is the intersection of 2 non-empty subsets. Why must that intersection also be non-empty? EG Why can't the first set be $ { 1 } $ and the second set be $ { 2 }$, which results in an empty intersection?  $\quad$ Note, there could be a more generous interpretation of your writeup, but in which case I'd encourage you to use those words explicitly (Or, ironically, delete some stuff), esp if you're concerned about proof verification.

There's a more concise proof.  Go back to $$\bigcap_{n\geq 0}A_n=\bigcap_{n\geq 0}(A_{2n}\cap A_{2n+1})$$  What is $A_{2n} \cap A_{2n+1}$?  You have a property that lets you simplify this.  (Also, note that \bigcap gives a better symbol for the arbitrary intersection.  You should still use \cap for the binary operation)

Thank you to both of you ! I updated my answer !
